# Why does this C program display different output when compiled on Windows?

Tags: c, windows

Now, I'm doing some problems on ProjectEuler.net, and this is the code I write for Problem #4:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int isPalindrome(int num)
{
    int length = floor(log10(abs(num))) + 1;
    int index = 0;
    int firstChar, lastChar;

    while (index <= (length / 2)) {

        firstChar = (num % (int)pow(10, length - index)) / pow(10, length - 1 - index);
        lastChar = (num % (int)pow(10, (index + 1))) / (pow(10, index));

        if (firstChar != lastChar) {
            return 0;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;
    int result = 0;
    int x, y;

    printf("Is 998001 a palidrome? %d\n", isPalindrome(998001));
    printf("Is 987789 a palidrome? %d\n", isPalindrome(987789));
    printf("Is 884448 a palidrome? %d\n", isPalindrome(884448));

    /* clock start */
    begin = clock();

    for (x = 999; x > 99; x--) {
        for (y = 999; y > 99; y--) {
            if (isPalindrome(x * y) && x * y > result) {
                result = x * y;
                printf("Found palindrome: %d\tX: %d\tY: %d\n", result, x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    end = clock();
    /* clock end */
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("ANSWER: %d\n", result);
    printf("ELAPSED TIME: %f\n", time_spent);

    return 0;
}
```

Not beautiful, but it works. When I compile this on GNU/Linux, it works fine. However on Windows 7 64-bit, I get this output:

[image: Windows output]

Expected output:

[image: Linux output]

Here's where it gets weird. If you swap lines 17 and 18 (the ones that start with firstChar and lastChar) it works fine on both Windows and GNU/Linux.

What is going on here? I compiled with mingw32 gcc like this:

```
gcc -v prob4.c -o prob4.exe -lm
```

Here's the compiler output: http://pastebin.com/rtarBtNY

Seriously guys what the hell is happening?

Comment: Please show your code here.  Don't link to external sites.

Comment: And do you really want to use a nested function like that?

Comment: You're converting a double to an int. You may want to add a small delta to the double from `pow` to make sure the value is greater than a whole integer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Like I said, it's not the best code. My question here is about the output.

Comment: @abginfo has the answer for you then: Don't use floating point for integer calculations.

Comment: That really doesn't answer anything. How does that explain why switching the two lines fixes it? And why does it always work on Linux?

Comment: @nanny The order in which the operations are performed might affect if the compiler will use temporaries to save intermediate results. Since floating points have limited resolution, re-ordering can change the value just enough to make a difference. There's no good reason to use floats here so don't.

Comment: It seems you've changed your code in the question but did not update the line numbers that need to be switched so I am not sure about that, however `8844448` is a palindrome if the length you are calculating is off by one. You seem to be doing a lot of floating point calculations with functions that potentially return slightly different results depending on the platform (`log10` and `pow`) and then truncating the results to `int`. This is likely the source of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the point about the line numbers. I'm not sure what everyone is mentioning floating points because that not what I'm concerned about. The code, as-is, works fine in Linux. It **only** breaks when the `lastChar` assignment comes before `firstChar`, and **only** on Windows.

Comment: @nanny I think *"functions that potentially return slightly different results depending on the platform"* is clear enough.

Comment: One potential step would be to ask your compiler to print the assembly of both versions and post the relevant lines in your question, so that we can compare them and see if it's really a precision issue (as has been suggested) or something else.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with floating points.
If you have the following code:

```
pow(10, 2)
```

you expect the value returned to be 100. It might be but there's no guarantee.
You will get a value close to 100 within some margin of error.

If the value returned is `100+d` (where `d` is within the precision) then when that value is converted to an `int` you get back `100`. If the value returned is `100-d` then when that value is converted to an `int` you get back `99`.

Answer (score 0):

That code shouldn't even compile. You're declaring a function inside of main.

If you move the isPalindrome() function definition outside of main I can
verify that it compiles in linux with no errors and no warnings.

Comment: Defining functions within other functions is a GCC extension.  It should work with GCC.

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix that. That's not really what my question is about though.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It probably should have been a comment.